# How to add a virtual attribute to a model in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I'm working on a RubyonRails/ActiveAdmin application. My RoR version is 4.2.5 and AA version is 1.0.0. I have a model `Message` as follows.

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, :content, presence: true

  def palindrome
    # return true/false
  end

end
```

As you see, I want to have a read-only attribute `palindrome` which only depends on the `content` of message. I want this attribute to be treated exactly like a normal attribute. By normal, I mean when I retrieve messages via `rails console` or request `json` format of messages, I want to see a `palindrome` attribute in the list. I would also like to have a filter for message by this attribute.

I'm not sure how could I achieve this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your model, you can write attribute accessors (reader/writer) for your virtual attribute `palindrome` attribute this way:

```
# attr_reader
def palindrome
  self[:palindrome]
end

# attr_writer
def palindrome=(val)
  self[:palindrome] = val
end

# virtual attribute
def palindrome
  #return true/false
end
```

And, as you are using Rails 4, you have to whitelist `palindrome` attribute like any other model attribute in your strong param definition inside your controller in order to able to mass assign the value of `palindrome`. Something like this:

```
# your_controller.rb
private

def your_model_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:palindrome)
end
```

Take a look at this [RailsCast on Virtual Attributes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes). Although, it's a bit old, but would be useful for concepts.

**Note:**

A virtual attribute will not show up in the param list automatically. But, you should be able to access it via Rails console like this: `Message.new.palindrome`. Also, you can expose this virtual attribute in your JSON API, for example if you are using [Active Model Serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#example), you can have: `attribute palindrome` in your `MessageSerializer` and then `palindrome` will be exposed to the JSON API.

Comment: Well, thank you. I have two questions. First, I don't want this attribute to be writable since it only depends to value of another attribute. Second, what does `self[:palindrome]` evaluate to?

Comment: If you don't need to write the attribute value, then you don't the setter method and whitelisting that in your strong param definition. `self[:palindrome]` will give you the value of the palindrome of `self` which is the instance of your model object. This is similar as `model_instance.palindrome`. Hope its clear now. Let me know if you have any other question.

Comment: virtual attribute will not show up in the param list automatically. But, he should be able to access it via Rails console like this: `model_instance.palindrome`. Also, he can expose this virtual attribute in his JSON API, for example if using Active Model Serializer, he can have: `attribute palindrome` in his `MessageSerializer` and then it will be exposed to the JSON API.

Comment: Thank you. It now works and I can expose to JSON API. I'm wondering how could I expose it to XML API as well?

Comment: What if I used virtual attribute as 'attr_reader' only, in this case when is the value needed to be set initially, since we can't do vr_attr_name = "", which throws exceptions it's readonly, conclusion, if i need virtual attribute for read only not writing, what do need to do in that case ?

Comment: This screencast is worth watching https://gorails.com/episodes/virtual-attributes-and-rails-5-attribute-api

Answer (score 32):

Ruby actually lets you create virtual attributes this way, which keeps you from having to manually create getter and setter methods:

```
attr_reader   :palindrome #getter
attr_writer   :palindrome #setter
attr_accessor :palindrome #both
```

You can also pass multiple arguments too:

```
attr_accessor :palindrome, :foo, :bar
```

The [documentation for it](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) isn't the greatest.

Comment: @RajaRaviVarma: you mix rails and ruby yourself in the first sentence :) . I'll fix the answer.

Answer (score 11):

Since Rails 5 you can also set virtual attributes like this:

```
attribute :palindrome, :boolean
```

It automatically casts the attribute to the specified type, which can be useful when the value comes from forms. [This GoRails video](https://gorails.com/episodes/virtual-attributes-and-rails-5-attribute-api) shows some really good examples of both using the `attr_accessor` and the `attribute` approach. [The documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attribute) also includes some examples.