# ActiveRecord model with feature in db and feature not in db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I currently have an existing model using ActiveRecord that grabs its features from a database. Is there a way to add a feature that does not correspond to a column in the db, but is in fact a function of one of the other columns? IE, I have existing feature `my_id` and I want to have another feature `double_id` which is a function of `my_id` (say twice the id) ?

Comment: yeah, just define a method. AR model is just a ruby class. With a lot of voodoo magic happening behind the scenes, yes, but for you it's just a class.

Comment: So are you saying I can just do something like 

--inside model file--
feature my_id:
`def new_feature( id)
     return some_function(id)
end
feature new_id: = new_feature(my_id:)`

Comment: The second part looks off, but the first part is good, yes

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727431/how-to-add-a-virtual-attribute-to-a-model-in-ruby-on-rails for information on using virtual attributes

Comment: That is exactly what I want! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a virtual attribute to a model in Ruby on Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727431/how-to-add-a-virtual-attribute-to-a-model-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Yeah this is a duplicate-- sorry I am new to ruby and didn't know what to call it.  Noted--  I want to add a 'virtual attribute' to a model. Thanks!