# SqlAlchemy non persistent column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I am trying to define a model using sqlalchemy such that one of the columns i only need in memory for processing, i do not have a corresponding database column for that. I need it such that when i save the in memory object, it should not try to persist that special column.

More context: I am mapping a json object to an sql alchemy object using python marshmallow library. In the json response i have additional fields which i do not need in the database but do need in memory for computation.

I searched for the sqlalchemy docs, but could not find a way to skip the persistence of certain columns.

```python
class AdSchema(Schema):
  """Schema Mapping class."""

  id = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
  available_formats = fields.List(fields.Str())

  @post_load
  def make_ad(self, data):
    return AdModel(**data)

class AdModel(Base):
  """Ad ORM class."""
  __tablename__ = 'ad_model'

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Am i missing something here?

What I am essentially looking for is a "virtual" attribute, similar to what is available in Rails ORM [How to add a virtual attribute to a model in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727431/how-to-add-a-virtual-attribute-to-a-model-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please add relevant model/table definitions & what you've tried

Comment: Can't you just use a plain old attribute?

Comment: Thats what i tried, but when i define the `__init__` method, sqlalchemy does not like it.

Comment: Does not like it how? In general SQLAlchemy does not care about the `__init__`: ["Mapping imposes no restrictions or requirements on the constructor (`__init__`) method for the class."](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/constructors.html)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around this by doing the following:

```
class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_model'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.non_persisted_column = kwargs['non_persisted_column']
        kwargs.pop('non_peristed_column')
        super().__init__(kwargs)
```

Effectively, a class attribute `non_persisted_column` is added to the class in the `__init__` method.  Then, `non_persisted_column` is removed from `kwargs` before `kwargs` is passed into the SQLAlchemy `Base` super class's `__init__` method, so SQLAlchemy will not raise an error and will not persist `non_persisted_column` to the database.

Comment: Any idea how to get this functionality using the declarative_base type?

Answer (score 0):

If you just add a variable to a `db.Model`-derived calss that is a "normal" data type (i.e. a string or integer) - as opposed to a `db.Column` - it can be used, and does not appear to have any affect on the actual database.