# Skip the default on onupdate defined, for specific update queries in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

If I have a list of posts, which have `created` and `updated` dates with a default attached `onupdate` callback.

Sometimes I need to flag the post, for `inappropriate reports` or similar actions. I do not want the `created` and `updated` dates to be modified.

How can I skip the defined `onupdate`, while making an `update` action?

Comment: Any restriction from using an `if` in the callback to check for the flag and update only if not changed?

Comment: How would I pass a parameter to this `onupdate` function? I'm looking in that direction, should work if found.

Comment: you could have attributes in your model that do not persist which can act as the parameter value. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49036259/sqlalchemy-non-persistent-column) might help

Comment: This doesn't work, as the non persistent attribute gets removed before `onupdate` function is called, else the db.session.commit() throws error, it seems. I might be doing something wrong. Trying to figure out.

Comment: I don't have a solution, I assumed that the flags would be persisted and can be checked onupdate. It would help to add these points to the question, the things you've tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQLAlchemy will apply a default [when](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/defaults.html#column-insert-update-defaults)

> no value was provided to the INSERT or UPDATE statement for that column

however the obvious workaround - explicitly setting the column to its current value - won't work because the session [checks](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.is_modified) whether the value has actually changed, and does not pass a value if it hasn't.  Here are two possible solutions, assuming SQLAlchemy 1.4+ and this model:

```py
class Post(db.Model):
    flag = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    last_updated = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=some_func, onupdate=some_func)
```

##### Use an event listener

Add a [before update listener](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.MapperEvents.before_update) that detects when the flag column is being modified, and [mark](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.flag_modified) the timestamp column as modified, even though its value is unchanged.  This will make SQLAlchemy add the current value to the update, and so the onupdate function will not be called.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
...
@sa.event.listens_for(Post, 'before_update')
def receive_before_update(mapper, connection, target):
    insp = sa.inspect(target)
    flag_changed, _, _ = insp.attrs.flag.history
    if flag_changed:
        orm.attributes.flag_modified(target, 'last_updated')
```

##### Use SQLAlchemy core instead of the ORM

SQLAlchemy core doesn't need a session, so the current timestamp value can be passed to an update to avoid triggering the onupdate function.  The ORM will be unaware of any changes made in this way, so if done within the context of a session affected objects should be refreshed or expired.  This is a "quick and dirty" solution, but might be good enough if flagging happens outside of the normal application flow.

```py
with db.engine.begin() as conn:
    posts = Post.__table__
    update = sa.update(posts).where(...).values(flag=True, last_updated=posts.c.last_updated)
    conn.execute(update)
```

Comment: I've changed the event listener type - the mapper event acts on the instance whereas the original before_flush session event required iterating over `session.dirty` to find modified `Post` instances.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply assign the columns with SQLAlchemy Core level Column objects to emit SQL like 'UPDATE post set created=post.created, updated=post.updated'.

```Python
class Post(Base):
  id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
  name=Column(String)
  created=Column(DateTime,onupdate=func.now())
  updated=Column(DateTime,onupdate=func.now())

post=session.query(Post).first()
post.name='updated post'
post.created= Post.__table__.c.created
post.updated= Post.__table__.c.updated
session.commit()
```

SQL emmitted:

```sql
UPDATE post SET name='updated post', created=post.created, updated=post.updated WHERE post.id=1;
```

Comment: A nice solution!